# SQL Data from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have four tables setup as follows

**Products**

- ProductCode
- ProductDescription
- ProductCategory

**BranchData**

- ProductCode
- BranchID
- BranchCosting

**BranchCostings**

- BranchCosting
- ListPrice
- CostPrice

I am trying to create a query which will display a table as follows

- ProductCode
- ProductDescription
- Branch1Cost
- Branch2Cost

with the following where clauses

- ProductCategory = 102,
- Branch2Cost != Branch1Cost

I have very limited SQL knowledge so am wondering how I would write a select query to select this data, I can get a table to display data from the product table and the Branch Data table but I am unable to get the Cost price for both branches from the Branch Costings table.

The SQL I am trying is as follows

```
Select P.ProductCode, P.ProductDescription, BC.CostPrice as B1Cost,         BC.CostPrice as B2Cost
From  Products P, BranchData BD, BranchCostings BC
Left Join BranchData on BC.BranchCosting = BD.BranchCosting
Where BD.BranchID = Branch1
```

I have been researching joins but this is where I am stuck, I did not know that you could join a table more than once and I am unsure which join to use (I think its a left join)

I have Just tried using the following which gives me all products in category 102 but it gives me these products for each cost price

```
Select P.ProductCode, P.ProductDescription, BC.CostPrice as B1Cost, BC.CostPrice as B2Cost
From  Products P, BranchCostings BC
Left Join Products as B0 on B0.BranchCosting = BC.BranchCosting
Left Join BranchData as B1 on B1.BranchCosting = BC.BranchCosting
Left Join BranchData as B2 on B2.BranchCosting = BC.BranchCosting
Where P.C_CATEGORY = 102
```

I now have the following which displays all the products in the category in the where statement but the B1CostPrice and the B2CostPrice are showing as NULL

```
Select ProductCode, ProductDescription, B1.CostPrice, B2.CostPrice
From Products
left Join BranchData as B0 on Products.ProductCode = B0.ProductCode
left Join BranchCostings as B1 on B0.BranchCosting = B1.BranchCosting
left Join BranchCostings as B2 on B0.BranchCosting = B2.BranchCosting
Where C_CATEGORY = 102
```

I have tried changing the join types to see if this would display correctly but it either shows no data at all or shows the correct products with the Cost Price columns as NULL

Data Structure and expected table

**Products**

```
ProductCode ProductDescription  Category
-----------------------------------------
Product1    Product Description 1       102
Product2    Product Description 2     102
Product3    Product Description 3     102
Product4    Product Description 4     102
Product5    Product Description 5     102
Product6    Product Description 6        99
```

**BranchData**

```
Product Code    BranchID     BranchCosting
Product1        B1           1
Product1        B2           2
Product2        B1           3
Product2        B2           4
Product3        B1           5
Product3        B2           6
Product4        B1           7
Product4        B2           8
Product5        B1           9
Product5        B2           10
Product6        B1           11
Product6        B2           12
```

**BranchCostings**

```
 BranchCosting  ListPrice   CostPrice
 1              2           1
 2              4           1
 3              6           3
 4              8           4
 5              10          5
 6              12          6
 7              14          7
 8              16          7
 9              18          9
 10             20          10
 11             22          11
 12             24          12
```

Expected Table

```
ProductCode     ProductDescription         B1CostPrice  B2CostPrice
Product2        Product Description 2      3              4
Product3        Product Description 3      5              6
Product5        Product Description 5      9             10
Product6        Product Description 6      11            12
```

In the above table Product1 and Product 4 are not shown as the CostPrice is the same for both B1 and B2

Comment: Show what you have written so far.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `JOIN` again.  Throw in a `WHERE`.

Comment: "unable to"...because? What did you try?What went wrong, exactly? Please show your code, and the results of executing it. Give us a problem to solve, rather than a requirement to implement from scratch, please. And also, what did you research yourself in order to try and overcome the difficulty? Hint: it is possible to join the same table more than once. Oh, and what database system are you using? e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, mySQL etc? That can affect the precise syntax you need, in some cases.

Comment: I have edited the question with the information you have requested, when I run the query it runs for ages and displays the same product thousands of times with the cost price for each of the other products

Comment: `From  Products P, BranchCostings BC` is the culprit. This old-style join syntax, without a WHERE to accompany it, will produce a cross-join. Always use the modern `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` syntax, for clarity. You also don't need to abstractly join BranchCostings here, because you're already joining it (more correctly) in the lines below. And confusingly you're also joining Products twice, which seems a bit unnecesary. Furthermore, you need to ensure BranchData is joined to Products correctly as well.

Comment: As for left join vs inner join, you can read about (and see examples of) the differences quite easily online. Find out what each one does, and you'll soon work out which one is needed in this case (which will depend on your exact data structure, and the precise output you want). Failing everything else, try each one in your own query (once you've got the rest of it basically right) and observe the difference in output (although again depending on your exact data, you might not actually see any difference in practice). There's nothing like learning by doing...

Comment: Thanks ADyson for the explanation but I am even more confused now than before I started, I have been looking at joins for the last 2 days before posting on here and have not got any further

Comment: specifically what don't you understand about what I said? My advice would be to build your query up one join at a time, reviewing the results each time, so you understand what effect it has. But certainly you must remove `, BranchCostings BC` to begin with - it makes no sense to join it like this.

Comment: P.S. For us to help you more effectively it would be really great to have some sample data, and then an example of the expected result of your query (based on that sample). It's much easier to write SQL when you can see the data and test with it. You could even consider making a simple demo using an online site (e.g. [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) or similar), which people can then use to try out queries and suggestion solutions.

Comment: I have added some sample data and what the table should look like after the select statement. Also is the select statement in my latest edit closer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have finally figured this out.

The select statement I used is as below

```
SELECT ProductCode, ProductDescription, B1.CostPrice as B1CostPrice, B2CostPrice as B2CostPrice
FROM Products
left JOIN BranchData as B0 on Products.ProductCode = B0.ProductCode
left JOIN BranchData as B9 on Products.ProductCode= B9.ProductCode
left join BranchCostings as B1 on B0.BranchCosting = B1.BranchCosting
left join BranchCostings as B2 on B9.BranchCosting = B2.BranchCosting
Where B0.Branch = Branch1 AND B9.Branch = Branch2 AND Products.Category = 102
```